# ¿Cómo crear una columna "Year" en un dataframe con un índice con fechas?

Tags: python-3.x

Dispongo del siguiente dataframe, cuyo índice son fechas.:

```
# Obtener cotizaciones de Iberdrola en Yahoo
IBE = pdr.DataReader("IBE.MC", "yahoo", start, end)
```

¿Cómo puedo crear una columna "Year", con el año correspondiente a la fecha que figura en el índice?. Agradeceré vuestra ayuda.

Comment: Prueba `pdr.index.year` o `pdr.index.dt.year` (no recuerdo ahora cuál de las dos era)

Comment: Efectivamente:  df["Year"] = df.index.year  es la solución. Gracias